# How can I generate the faces of a cube in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, 3d, geometry

I am writing a function in Haskell that takes a `Point` and a `Double` that represent the center and side length of a cube, respectively.

A `Point` is `type Point = [Double]`.

The function signature is `getCubeFaces :: Cube -> [Face]` where a `Face` is `data Face = Face [Point]` and a `Cube` is `data Cube = Cube Point Double`.

My question is, how do I go about doing this? I've tried the naive approach of

```
[ Face [ [-1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1] ...
```

and listing all the 6 faces as described by their 8 points - but this is *really* ugly.

Is there a more intuitive / patterned way to go about this (without having access to a normal vector)?

Comment: Given that the cube could be rotated arbitrarily around its center, how can you go about finding its exact vertices given only its center point and side length?

Comment: @ChristianTernus That's a good point. I was assuming that it's laying "flat" on the ground - meaning that there is no rotation.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with your `Cube`s? What's best depends on the use. If you're eventually going to render them using something like OpenGL, then you'll probably want them to be saved as vertices since that's what OpenGL needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let

```
type Vector = Point
a <+> b = zipWith (+) a b --vector addition
a <*> b = map (*b) a --vector scalar multiplication
```

Then, I suggest two methods. The cubes are centered at `0, 0, 0`, with side length of `2`. You can later `map (\face -> map (\point -> point <*> sideLength/2 <+> center)`. First

```
face :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector -> Face
face x y z = [x <+> (y <*> i) <+> (z <*> j) | i <- [-1, 1], j <- [-1, 1]]

cube :: [Face]
cube = let
    axes = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
    directions = zipWith (\ds i -> map (<*>i) ds) (permutations axes) (cycle [1, -1])
  in map (\[x, y, z] -> face x y z) directions
```

And second,

```
cube' :: [Face]
cube' = let
    points = [[x, y, z] | x <- [-1, 1], y <- [-1, 1], z <- [-1, 1]]
    pair i = partition (\x -> x !! i > 0) points
  in map pair [0..2] >>= (\(a, b) -> [a, b])
```

While the second is shorter, note that the first allows you more flexibility when you figure out that you actually wanted `type Face = [Triangle]`.

Comment: This is perfect - thank you. There is probably not nearly enough room, but could you briefly elaborate on why I should have my `Face`s defined by `Triangle`s and not `Point`s?

Comment: Triangles, because if you needed this for OpenGL, you'd probably do `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, ...)` and that would expect to get a face as 6 vertices (i.e. two triangles). No other reason.

Comment: Karolis, this is hindsight speaking. You were correct.